# How to Update Database using Datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

I would like to update Database when any Cell is updated in the GridView on particular button click.

Database connection

```
    private void databaseBindingToGrid()
    {
     connetionString = @"initial catalog = Test; integrated security = SSPI; data source = KITS13AUG2019-I\JAGDEESH_SQL;";
     conSql = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
     conSql.Open();
     cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "Select * from AGENTS";
     cmd.Connection = conSql;
     adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     dt = new DataTable("AGENTS");
     adpt.Fill(dt);
     datGridView.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
     }
```

I tried like this but not working

```
    private void C1ToolbarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           adpt.Update(dt);
           MessageBox.Show("Updated");
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples )?

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Is there an error? Are you familiar with profiling SQL Server to see what commands are being received?

Comment: You have supplied the adapter's select command, but you have shown no code that sets the update command (or insert or delete commands). You can [view this sample project](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid) to see an example. It is winforms, not WPF but the data access code would be the same.

Comment: You need to either set the commands or use commandbuilder to generate them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generating-commands-with-commandbuilders  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters

Answer (score 0):

You must declare a connection class which is return your connection open.

```
public SqlConnection Connection()
    {
      connetionString = @"initial catalog = Test; integrated security = SSPI;    
      data source = KITS13AUG2019-I\JAGDEESH_SQL;";
      conSql = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
      conSql.Open();

      return conSql;
    }
```

After that you declare Datagridview elements in your form load action.

```
public void FillDataGridView()
{
   cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "Select * from AGENTS";
   cmd.Connection = Connection();
   adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   dt = new DataTable("AGENTS");
   adpt.Fill(dt);
   datGridView.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

And now you can use

```
private void C1ToolbarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           //it is call your data grid view when you click button
           FillDataGridView();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about updating changes.